# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: blog_category

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I keep getting the error when i try running `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and `python3 manage.py migrate`

i have checked over a lot of posts and they all say to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and  python3 `manage.py migrate` or even `python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` but the problem is that i get this error when i run those commands as well as when i run `python3 manage.py runserver`:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: blog_category
```

the other problem is that i don't every have any code that says `blog_category` so i don't even know where django is getting that from. i'v tried different venv's to see if other installed programs were the problem but the error persists. Please help.

Comment: `blog_category` is referring to a Category model within your Blog app, do you have something that fits that description? Double check all of your names and imports, otherwise it could just be a migration error that needs to be reversed and re-applied

Comment: might be interesting to look at this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264603/git-corrupts-sqlite-database  I got this OperationalError after git indeed corrupted my db.sqlite3 file. It is an easy fix to delete the db file, copy over a fresh one (make a new dummy project to generate it), flush the database, and then make migrations from that point.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I was unable to make new migrations even after manually deleting the migrations. I noticed that my db.sqlite3 file turned into a text file after forking my project from github.

Here's what you can do:

- Ensure that your db.sqlite3 file in your project root folder has the extension ".sqlite3", it should not be without a file extension. Also make sure that it is not an empty file (0 KB).

You should not be able to open the db file and see this:[image]

This is not what should be. The way around fixing such an issue is to copy the db.sqlite3 file over from another project (as it will keep generating a false one otherwise). Then make some changes to admin.py or models.py so that the database will realize it needs to do something (make migrations), and then luckily - you should now be able to make migrations (python manage.py makemigrations).

If the above does not provide resolution, this is how you can completely reset the database:

```
    python manage.py flush
```

Create the superuser again and make any necessary migrations:

```
    python manage.py createsuperuser
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

It is also important to ensure that you have no active code in your project which would try to query data from a database table which no longer exists.
Realize that you now have an empty database.

If I would have code running in the project that would try to retrieve data from a database object that used to be there in the past, something like:

```
 p = Category.objects.get(title=flower_type)

 print(p.flower_set.first())
 print(p.flower_set.last())
```

It would cause problems, since there are no database entries, and there is no data to query.  It's something to watch out for.